# A right triangle with sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Imagine a right triangle with sides:

Long side C is $4n$, sides $b$ and $a$ are $2n$ and $n$, where $n$ is an integer.

How many right triangles are of this form?

My attempt:

$$16n^2 = 4n^2 + n^2$$ $$11n^2 = 0$$

$n$ is not an integer. No right triangles can be made this way.

Had this on an entrance exam for medicine...It seemed too obvious to be true...?

Comment: Actually $n$ is an integer, $n = 0$, but your conclusion is right there are no right triangles satisfying the givens.

Comment: Yeah, we of course exclude n=0, forgot to mention that. But thank you, I was tearing my hair at this one as a maths major because it was just too obvious to actually be true.

Comment: Yep. You did a proof by contradiction, you assumed there existed such a triangle and you know right triangles satisfy  $c^2 = a^2 + b^2$, but you found no such triangle exists.

Comment: Not only are there no right triangles possible, but there are no triangles possible.  Assuming the sides have positive lengths, $n+2n<4n$

Comment: There's a reason they call it The Triangle Inequality.

Comment: If we have discovered $"n+2n<4n"$, there is no need to go on any further.!

Comment: ... so... would you like this question deleted?  If you want, you can just answer the question yourself and mark that as accepted.  @user3200098